# see the server error after ajax request with laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i receive the 500 (Internal Server Error) after make a ajax request on laravel 5.2.

as I can see what is wrong?

at some point I saw that there is a command that starts with tails, but can not find it.

thanks.

code:

html:

```
<form role="form" id="Login" >

              {{ csrf_field() }}


               <label >Correo electronico: </label>
               <input id="correo" type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Enter email">
                <id id="emailError"></id>

               <label >Contraseña:</label>
               <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
               <id id="passwordError"></id>



                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="Submit" onclick="LogIn(event)" >Iniciar sesion</button>

        </form>
```

js:

```
function LogIn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: Login,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            email: $('#correo').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
        },
        beforeSend: function()
        {

            $("#emailError").fadeOut();
            $("#passwordError").fadeOut();

        },

        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.success){
                console.log(data);

                if(typeof data.error.email !== 'undefined'){
                    $('#correo').css('border-color', 'red');
                    $('#emailError').fadeIn(10, function () {
                        $("#emailError").html(data.error.email);

                    })
                }
                if(typeof data.error.password !== 'undefined'){
                    $('#password').css('border-color', 'red');
                    $('#passwordError').fadeIn(10, function () {
                        $("#passwordError").html(data.error.password[0]);


                    })
                }
            }else{

                console.log(data);
                $('#LogIn').modal('hide');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Modals\Users;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Modals\Users as user;
use Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }


    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function entrar (Request $request){

        $validator= Validator::make($request->all(),[

            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:2',

        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()){

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'error' => $validator->errors()->toArray()
            ]);

        }else{

            return response()->json([
               'success' =>true
            ]);
        }

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
        {

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true
            ]);
        }else

        {
            return response()->json([

                'success' => false,
                'error' => 'not login'

            ]);
        }



    }


}
```

log:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/Entrar 500 (Internal Server Error)   jquery.min.js:4 
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
LogIn @ scripts.js:82
onclick @ VM18805:87
```

Comment: You might be missing the CSRF token. If you open the inspector in your browser and go to the "Network" tab (that's what it's called on Chrome) you'll be able to click on the failing request and view the detailed response.

Comment: Regarding the "command that starts with tails", you're probably talking about the `tail` command. You can use it to monitor your laravel.log file. Assuming you are in the project's root folder, you can run `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`. The `-f` option tells `tail` to follow the log file.

Comment: tails is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or batch file. :/

Comment: @RecoJhonatan Tail is only available on Mac/Linux by default.

Comment: @ceejayoz what could use for windows?? :/

Comment: @RecoJhonatan http://stackify.com/11-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/

Comment: @RecoJhonatan Maybe you can open explorer and navigate to <project-root>/storage/logs/ to see the latest log file, If you see the error please let us know so we can help you :)

Comment: @weigreen see the post. :)

Comment: @RecoJhonatan We need server's log not browser's log

Comment: `url: Login`  isnt this supposed to be url: `{{ url('login') }}` and try to comment everything in the method and just return a simple response to check if the error is from the method it self or not

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Login is a variable

Comment: @RecoJhonatan forgive my low js level